# If a user is a member of different groups, which group's permissions does he have in AEM?

Tags: aem

Suppose `user A` is a member of `author` and `approver` groups. `Author` group doesn't have the permission to replicate content and `approver` group does have. I tried it and `user A` doesn't get the permission to replicate.

So the "`deny`" permission takes the precedence or is there any other rule?

And if this is the case, then do I have to remove `user A` from author group so that he has the permission to replicate content or Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the order in which the rules are applied.You can understand this by looking at `rep:policy` node at each of your project node and the order of permissions applied under each of these policy node.

Yes `Deny` rule takes the precedence by default and `Deny` first is the approach we need to follow for easier maintenance of permissions(else it will be cumbersome for maintaining permissions (Example like we have to remove all the allowed permission for the newly created group/users))

Example below screenshot allow rule will apply on the nodes even-tough they are contradicting each other.
[image: ACL Permissions]

Have a look at this [article](http://aempodcast.com/2015/permissions/setting-permissions-smooth-aem-authoring-experience/#.WIlcyxsrLIV) for more better understanding.

Comment: FYI, to see the screenshot above, you need to be on the node in question and select the "Access Control" tab...the "local access control policies" can be read bottom up...meaning starting at the bottom, the first permission that applies will take effect

Comment: Thanks Guys! In that case what do I need to do, when the user has to be a member of both the groups, and he should have permission to replicate content?

Comment: check on the node where the permissions are not applied, and move up/down so that `Allow ` can be the one on effect on node.